# When doing SUM() in SQL on a row, how do you add a flag saying if it was actually summed or not?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to flag if a row was actually summed to another row or not while using SUM(). There are also rows that calculate min(), max(), and I am keeping track of a row number to take only the first row.

I have been looking around on google, but haven't had much luck in figuring this out, I have a SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb4f3/6, which I know is complex. You can take out the WHERE rn = 1 and add a column to see the row numbers if it helps. Basically what I need is to add a column that says if it was aggregated or not... I believe the best way would to somehow see in row 1 if there is a second row or not. Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

```
select
    userid, favoriteanimal,
    row_number()  over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp order by firstday) as rn,
    min(firstday) over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp) as firstday,
    max(lastday)  over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp) as lastday,
    sum(daysused) over (partition by name, email, favoriteanimal, grp) as daysused
from concatenated
```

This would be the SQL I'm trying to get information from, pretty much if the row was aggregated (min, max or sum) there is more than one row number entry for it. So I imagine there's a way to "update" row 1 if there's more than one row?

Comment: `COUNT(*) OVER (...) > 1`???

Comment: What do you mean by a new column indicating if the row was aggregated? What does that mean here? What are you expecting as output in your fiddle?

Comment: I would expect userid 2 and 3 to have a flag that they were aggregated. I mean that they had one or more rows summed to them. If you look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb4f3/4 you can see that those two have multiple rows.